# JQuery Radio Buttons In ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want some radio buttons styled [the way JQuery does it](http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio). I've now got demo code working that shows that in a minimal HTML page, but I need to do that now in an ASP.NET C# page. The following code works fine, where REDACTED points to a local-network server:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Button - Radios</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://REDACTED/_Kris_Sandbox/css/jquery/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://REDACTED/_Kris_Sandbox/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://REDACTED/_Kris_Sandbox/js/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#radio" ).buttonset();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <div id="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio"><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked"><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio"><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But the following shows me ordinary, non-JQuery-styled radio buttons. The date picker *does* work (showing that JQuery is running) and messages show up as a pop-up and in the console, showing that the function is running, but the buttons aren't being styled.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="travel_temp.aspx.cs" Inherits="_idx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head id="hgs_head" runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JQuery Test</title>

    <!-- The following links have been commented out. The internal links point to copies of JQueryUI files that exist and are freshly downloaded from the makers' site. -->
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://REDACTED/_Kris_Sandbox/css/jquery/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://REDACTED/_Kris_Sandbox/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://REDACTED/_Kris_Sandbox/js/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Radio button styling -->
    <script>
        $(function () {
            console.log("ready!");
            alert("Hi!");
            $("radio").buttonset();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body id="hgs_body" runat="server">
    <p>Date Picker using JQuery:</p>
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date"><script>$("#date").datepicker();</script>

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div id="main">
        <p>Radio Buttons using JQuery:</p>
        <form class="messages" id="messages" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"/>
            <div id="radio">
                <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio"><label for="radio1">Twilight</label>
                <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked"><label for="radio2">Dash</label>
                <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio"><label for="radio3">Rarity</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I figure the problem has to do with this page being ASP.NET with the buttons being created through an .aspx page (the .aspx.cs page is blanked out for demo purposes by the way). But the point of using "$(function" is that it only runs once the page is fully assembled, so the radio buttons should already be there.

What do I need to do, to make the styling work?

(Follow-up note: I didn't do it in this example, but the actual buttons are ASP.NET code. That wasn't the problem though; see answer. If you're having the same problem note that you apparently need to call the JQuery function to style them again if the page updates.)

Comment: Your radio buttons are not created through asp.net engine. They are just plain html controls. If they were, each radio element would have runat="server" attribute applied to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During page load, you are assigning the buttonset property to element which is of type `tag : radio`. No such element exists in your `DOM`. You need to target the `div` where you want to apply the buttonset. In short, you are missing `'#'` in your selector.

```
$(function () {
            console.log("ready!");
            alert("Hi!");
            $("#radio").buttonset();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. You answered the question correctly as I wrote it. I then realized that I had not only forgotten the #, but that in my example I hadn't demonstrated using ASP radio buttons, and that I had failed to enclose those buttons in my real code with a <div> tag. So the lesson is: use # to indicate the ID of a <div> that encloses the buttons.

Comment: also remember while using asp.net controls ( may a div you are trying to apply buttonset ) , either set the ClientIDMode="Static" as an attribute to div or use server side expression to get the correct id : '<%=divID.ClientID %>'